# Angle information(degree) between AR camera and target object on a plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have a question, please help and thanks!
I want to know how to show the Angle information(degree) between AR camera and target object on a plane. (Using Smartphone)
And I want to know how to "code" with Unity and AR Foundation.

I tried using some code(below), but it seems only work on Distance, not work on Angle...

Thank again!

```
void Start ()
{
    //get the components
    private ARRaycastManager RayManager;
    private GameObject visual;
    public Camera CameraStart;
    public Text textField2;
    public Text textField;
    float distance;
    float angle;
    RayManager = FindObjectOfType<ARRaycastManager>();
    visual = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
}


void Update ()
{
    // shoot a raycast from the center of the screen
    List<ARRaycastHit> hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
    RayManager.Raycast(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2), hits, TrackableType.Planes);

    RaycastHit hit;
    //Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    // check if we hit an AR plane, update the position and rotation 
    if(hits.Count > 0)
    {
        transform.position = hits[0].pose.position;
        transform.rotation = hits[0].pose.rotation;
        distance = Vector3.Distance(CameraStart.transform.position, transform.position);
        textField.text = distance.ToString("N2") + "meter"; 

        Physics.Raycast(transform.position, out hit);
        angle = Vector3.Angle(hit.normal, transform.forward);            
        textField2.text = angle.ToString("N2") + "degree";

        if(!visual.activeInHierarchy)
        visual.SetActive(true);
            
    }
}
```

}

Comment: by not working what do you mean? what is the output you obtain?

Comment: The "angle" information can be successfully generated, but the output data of the system is incorrect. For example, the output degree of the system is 96 degrees, but the actual degree is 45 degrees.
Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the ray hits:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, out hit)) {
    angle = Vector3.Angle(hit.normal, transform.forward);            
    textField2.text = angle.ToString("N2") + "degree";
} else {
    Debug.LogError("Did not hit")     
}
```

Also I would make sure that the target has a collider and that the [layer mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) is correct.